# Factory Design Pattern correctly used?

Tags: design-patterns, clean-code

I'm trying to write an Entity-Component System and I want to have different factories creating different kinds of entities. For example the HumanEntityFactory class will create human entities.

Would it break separation of concerns if I store the different types of human that the factory can create, or should I create a factory for each kind of human?

```
HumanEntityFactory
===========
-HashMap<String, Component[]> humanEntityTypeComponents

+addHumanType(String typeName, Component[] components)

+createHuman(String type)
```

```
Entity
======
-HashMap<String, Component> components
```

Comment: It's unclear from your question whether "human type" is an entity in its own right, or whether it is merely a property of "human."  Also, Separation of Concerns doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: "human type" are common properties for different kinds of human, for example the maximum speed of human child might be A, whereas the maximum speed of a HumanSprinter might be B.

Comment: If you're using a factory for storage you haven't built a factory. You've built a repository. Factories make things.

Comment: It also creates the humans of the certain types... Does this violate SRP?

Comment: SRP doesn't mean what you think it means either.

Comment: The way I approach this personally is basically just register creation functions for "preset" entities with component combos and fields that are commonly used. I just register them by name with an interned string and a function pointer in C that gets called when the client requests to create an entity with the matching interned string. I suppose if you look at it in terms of factories, there's just one central factory, and it doesn't know what it's supposed to create. In my system, if there was a "human" entity, it would register the functions, by name, to create it.

Comment: I find it a little bit odd to have multiple factories given the flexibility of ECS. You could just have one where you publish new creation methods for entities by name, and then other parts of the codebase (or users running scripts) can then create those entity "presets" by name. In some cases it might also make sense for your systems to be able to create certain entities by request, like an `ItemSystem` being able to create a new item entity. At other times you might register a central entity by name, like `Broadsword`, at which point it gives you back an entity with all the components.

Comment: @RobertHarvey in this case the question about SRP in my comment was justified, since the question was wether storage of types of humans and generation of these types was a violation of SRP, which incidentally it is. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724469/difference-between-single-responsibility-principle-and-separation-of-concerns), `Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) – every object should have a single responsibility, and that all its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility`.

Comment: If I were you, I'd read up a bit more on the Single Responsibility Principle.  It's sole purpose is to provide guidance for avoiding the creation of "kitchen sink" classes that *do too much.*  Data Access classes routinely provide storage, retrieval ***and*** instantiation services, and this is not considered a violation of SRP.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thank you, I'll read up on it, do you have any good primers on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is important to make a [difference between Single Responsibility Principle (SRP, related to Clean Code) and Separation of Concerns (SOC, related to engineering at large)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1724469/3723423).

#### Analyse of your design

The [Entity-Component-System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system) has the purpose of avoiding a rigid compile-time class hierarchy by using a flexible data structure based on a flat Entity type enriched through run-time composition with [components](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html).

I understand that:

- your `HumanEntityFactory` creates human `Entities` of different kind,  each kind being characterized by a different set of default `Components`.
- in order to keep the system flexible, you define at run-time the  standard components to use for each kind of human (e.g. `addHumanType("Warrior", { new Sword(), new WarriorRenderer() })` )
- then a new human is instantiated by the factory with the method `createHuman()` (e.g.  `createHuman("Warrior")`, `createHuman("Magician")` and so on). I'll assume that the standard components are cloned, in case they have a state (e.g. `defensivePower`, `offensivePower`, `depreciation`).

#### Single responsibility

The name of this principle is somewhat misleading.  So let's look at R.C.Martin's own explanations:  [SRP is about reasons to change, which are in general related to people responsibilities](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html).

What are the possible changes that may require a change of the factory ?

- change of the Entity interface.  That's natural because we factor Entities.
- change the Component creation logic.  Someone may for example change the way the Components are created, moving from cloning to a factory.
- change of the way the kinds of humans are managed, together with their component "templates".

I see here 3 different reasons for change, so no, it's not compliant with the SRP.

Note that having more "templates", i.e. more kinds of humans, will not require any changes to the factory class. So this is not relevant for SRP.

#### Separation of concerns

The [separation of concerns](https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/) is about modularity and decoupling. Your factory class seems to addresses two distinct concerns:

- First, it manages the human types (via the method `addHumanType()` and the property `humanEntityTypeComponents`).
- Then, it creates a new Entity according to the configuration

The first concern, is something that is related to the configuration. You certainly do this during the initialization, and probably it's the consequence of loading some configuration file.  The second concern is unrelated.

So this design does not respect the separation of concerns either.

#### Way forward

The first thing would be to have a class managing the configuration of human entities.

The second thing would be to have a generator class, that generates a list of components for a given kind, based on the configuration.

The entity factory could then be instantiated by injecting the configuration and the generator,